# how block this spam bot using htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, security, spam, google-analytics

I have this spam bot showing in google analytics ([screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9tkt.png)).
I tried blocking it using this htaccess configuration

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (Trump) [NC]
RewriteRule .* www.google.com [L]
```

If the Accept-language contains the word "Trump" it got redirected to google.

I'm still getting new hits.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to detect the user-agent of this bot and block that user agent using the following code in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} user_agent_name_here [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

If there are a lot of different user-agent values each time then:

```
RewriteEngine On  
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^$" invalid_user_agent
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^user-agent1" invalid_user_agent
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^user-agent2" invalid_user_agent
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^user-agent2" invalid_user_agent
Deny from env=invalid_user_agent
```